# Windows Explorer Context Menu Question

Tags: c#

I have a TreeView that represents some files/folders in the Windows file system. i want to be able to right click one and display the standard Windows context menu. The node's tag contains the file path.
I have spent a fair amount of time researching and I found this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/shellContextMenu.aspx

However, it seems to be missing the "Rename" item. So I want to get that back..

I also want to know how to handle the functions. For example, if the user renames or deletes a file, I want to remove that node/rename that node accordingly.

I am programming in C#, .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the CMF_CANRENAME flag in the uFlags parameter to [IContextMenu.QueryContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776097(VS.85).aspx) to indicate that your host application supports renaming items.

Comment: How would I integrate it with my tree view to invoke the edit mode? There is an IsEditable property on the tree so I want to be able to support it correctly.

Comment: After TrackPopupMenu returns the selected command id, you'd pass it to IContextMenu.GetCommandString with GCS_VERB. If the returned verb is "rename", you would use the built in editing capability of the TreeView control (TreeNode.BeginEdit). Finally, apply the name change by calling IShellFolder.SetNameOf. You may also want to check if IShellFolder.GetAttributesOf returns SFGAO_CANRENAME before adding the Rename menu item at all.